# Shortcut for CakePHP view helper: `foo()` instead of `$this->MyHelper->foo()`?

Tags: cakephp

I find myself using a certain helper a lot in Views. I call it like this:

```
$this->MyHelper->foo()
```

It's a big nuisance to type this construct every time. I wish i could use a shortened version instead:

```
foo()
```

It should be available in Views.

How do i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what IDE and type-completion is for.
You will open a can of worms and collisions with such an approach.

Also it doesn't make your code any more useful or better to understand btw.
The opposite: It is destined to blow up.

But if you must you can create yourself wrappers to access it via

```
$this->foo()
```

as long as there is no collision and you write yourself a custom View class to allow that.
foo() itself - if you think about it - is not possible as this would require static access and destroys the whole idea of reusable objects.

But again: It's a bad idea to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

It is a simple PHP variable assigning technique:

Use:

$obj = $this->MyHelper;

$obj->foo();

Hope this will be helpful to you.